# dynamically creating multiple dropdown in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue in dynamically creating select dropdown in angular js, changing one dropdown option make changes on the rest of the dropdowns. My requirement is to use same data option in all dropdown and to get the selected option in each dropdown. How do I over come this problem?

example:

```
  <div ng-repeat ="option in options">
   <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model='newcategory.option'
   ng- change="optsChanged()"required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option
   in useroptions'>
   </select> 
  <div>
```

I need to create a dropdown for each row of a table that has the same options, but it should be a different instance or different model to be assigned dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean make them all the same and if one changes the others reflect same value? Question is very vague

Comment: I did some edits in my question

Comment: I did some edits in my question and added a few lines of code

Comment: still not clear what your issue is. Can you create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co

Comment: here i added the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/2m9uErhRAbyo7vDUCF9m?p=preview

Comment: try this... you haven't idendified really what you want these selects to bind to  http://plnkr.co/edit/juOJnLYtvdx2vBUC887t?p=preview

Comment: This is looking good, but the problem here is the first or default option is blank, how to fix that?

Comment: previously I had the same problem, resolved by this line of code                             $scope.newcategory = {option:$scope.useroptions[0].value};

Comment: It has been resolved by adding an default option between select tags Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the index as the subscript for the ng-model **ng-model='newcategory.option[$index]'**.. currently you are using the same ng-model for all the select boxes which is causing the issue

```
   <div ng-repeat ="option in options">
       <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model='newcategory.option[$index]'
            ng-change="optsChanged()"required ng-options='option.value as option.name for    option in useroptions'>
       </select> 
  <div>
```